# Everything says my disk is full

Tags: 20.04

Attached is the picture I see in Webmin showing my used space under /.  This problem started about a month ago.  Thinking that I perhaps had some hidden file or a file that was remaining due to being attached to a process I just upgraded to a 256GB SSD, which is now showing full as well.  I have looked at the following issues and none of them had applied to me.  I can't even locate the file(s) that is the culprit.  I wish it was a log file but all of my log files show WAY less than 200GB+.  Is there a way to scan the drive, bit by bit, to find where all of this space is going?

[Screen shot of WebMin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgtrg.png)

- [Ubuntu says the disk is full but it's not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135066/ubuntu-says-the-disk-is-full-but-its-not)
- [Ubuntu One says that my account is full, but it's not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31197/ubuntu-one-says-that-my-account-is-full-but-its-not)
- [Ubuntu thinks Btrfs disk is full but it's not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464074/ubuntu-thinks-btrfs-disk-is-full-but-its-not)
- [Why can't Ubuntu see any free space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5130/why-cant-ubuntu-see-any-free-space)
- [My root partition keeps filling to 100% capacity, but I can't figure out why!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852049/my-root-partition-keeps-filling-to-100-capacity-but-i-cant-figure-out-why)

I can't get df -h to format corecttly so I've attached a screen shot.

[Output of df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwchd.png)

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              3.2G  3.8M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  228G  227G     0 100% /
tmpfs                               16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  220M  690M  25% /boot
/dev/sdg1                           29G  112K   29G   1% /media/USB_Key
/dev/sda1                          511M  7.9M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdf1                          7.3T  3.9T  3.5T  54% /media/USB_Backup
/dev/mapper/NAS                     11T  6.7T  4.4T  61% /media/NAS
tmpfs                              3.2G  4.0K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

[Screen Shot of ncdu output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdDL7.png)

[Screen shot of ncdu output of /media directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbUG3.png)

Also, when I run ncdu on / and exclude the /media directory (which has my external mounts) this is what ncdu reports at the bottom:

Total disk usage:  36.8 GiB  Apparent size: 128.0 TiB  Items: 839806

Comment: The links were mearly an attempt to not get this labled as a duplicate.  I have attempted all of the solutions posted in all of those links.  They pertain to my inquiry such that they are all labeled solutions for "why is my hardrive keep filling up."  Again, I don't think this is a duplicate so I am trying to show that is all.

Summary of what I have tried:
Deleting logs
Disconnecting processes from deleted files
It's not a reserved space issue
Unlike these articles, my issue keeps happening, even with a bigger ssd

Comment: The 2nd line in the df output confirms that your root directory is full, so I don't get the "it clearly is not" statement in the question title.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, agreed but I can't seem to find the reason why...

The screen shot from WebMin shows way less than 256GB if you add up all of the directories.  I guess that's what I meant.

Comment: This line clearly states your disk is full. /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 228G 227G 0 100% /

Comment: Do you have ncdu installed? I find that a useful tool. Run it on / using sudo and the results will be instructive. It might take a little while to run. Or for a gui, run baobab as root.

Comment: @OrganicMarble  Yes I do.  I edited the original post with a screen shot of the output.  /media is mounted to a different physical array.  If you add up every other line it comes out to way less than 256GB.  I guess my biggest issue is not knowing where the disk space usage is coming from..

Comment: From your `df -h` output, I don't see `/media` being mounted to a different physical device. `/media/USB_Key`, `/media/USB_Backup` and `/media/NAS` are separate devices, but `/media` itself isn't. Maybe you have something big in `/media` directory itself, and not in subdirs listed above, mounted on seperate devices?

Comment: @raj Good call.  Unfortunatly, I just ran ncdu on that directory and only got back those 3 directories you listed above and an additional directory that shows 4KB.  I've since deleted that directoy.  So it doesn't look like anything else is in /media.  Great idea, though.

Comment: Maybe some of these answers will help you to get detailed listing of directory sizes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370575/how-to-combine-tree-with-the-directory-size

Comment: @raj Thanks.  Actually ncdu is better than those.  :) 

I did try running du though, and it gave me the same result.  There are some big directories but nothing near adding up to 256GB.

Comment: Try `sudo du -h --max-depth=3 / | sort -r -h | less`. It will show you sizes of all directories 3 levels deep from top, sorted by largest first. Maybe you find something...

Comment: @raj Thanks for the help.  That came up the same as ncdu, nothing that adds up to 256GB.  It adds up to around 37GB.

Comment: This looks very weird to me: "Total disk usage: 36.8 GiB Apparent size: 128.0 TiB "

Comment: This may be repetitive to @raj's comment but just to be explicit - unmount everything in /media, and then run ncdu.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I agree.  Best I can tell it's the kcore file in the /proc directory.  Apparently this is normal according to this article:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170795/proc-kcore-file-is-huge

Answer (score 2):

What it ended up being is that despite it looking like /media/USB_Backup was monted, it actually wasn't and my backups where going to my primary drive.  I deleted the entry for that drive in etc/fstab, rebooted, cleared the directory, recreated the line in fstab again, rebooted again, and now it is actually pointing to the external drive.  I tested by rebooting with it unplugged and it was empty, rebooted with it plugged in and it had contents.  My primary drive is now showing almost empty.  Thanks to @OrganicMarble for making me unmount the drives (I was being lazy).  Probably would have never found it, if not for that. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Well, that was really weird... disk shown as mounted by `df` but in fact not mounted... Never seen something like this. Good that you found it out!